# Remove action from empty row of v-data-table Vuetify

Tags: vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm trying to make my v-data-table on static height, so i decided to add empty rows.
After i add action which delete row, and now i have icons on empty rows to.
How can i delete them?
[You can see image of what i mean here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2l3MM.png)

```
<template v-slot:item.action="{ item }">
      <v-icon
        small
        @click="deleteItem(item)"
      >
        mdi-delete
      </v-icon>
    </template>
```

[Full code of component on codepen](https://codepen.io/amvicc/pen/BaaRXmP)

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if `item` has a property (e.g. `name`), since your `defaultItem` is an empty Object.

```html
<v-icon
  v-if="item.hasOwnProperty('name')"
  ...
>...</v-icon>
```